# Question about limits of quotient of functions.

Tags: limits

let:
$c\in \mathbb{R^*}=\{\mathbb{R},-\infty,+\infty\}$

$$\lim_{ x \to c}f(x)=0,\\\lim_{ x \to c}g(x)=+\infty\\\lim_{ x \to c}h(x)=-\infty$$

then:

$$\lim_{  x \to c }(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})=0?\\\lim_{  x \to c }(\frac{g(x)}{f(x)})=+\infty?\\\lim_{  x \to c }(\frac{h(x)}{f(x)})=-\infty?\\\lim_{  x \to c }(\frac{f(x)}{h(x)})=0?$$

is it right ?

Comment: The infinite limits don't look right.  It depends on if $f$ is positive or negative as its value approaches zero.

Comment: Don't use newline(\\\) in the title it looks weird,also it's more useful if you have some text in your title,what you wrote is certainly not descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

These are right:

> $$\lim_{  x \to c }(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})=0?\\\lim_{  x \to c }(\frac{f(x)}{h(x)})=0?$$

But you need to be careful with:

> $$lim_{  x \to c }(\frac{g(x)}{f(x)})=+\infty?\\\lim_{  x \to c }(\frac{h(x)}{f(x)})=-\infty?$$

It's not because $g(x) > 0$, that the fraction $\tfrac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ will be positive: that depends on the sign of $f(x)$. And since $f(x) \to 0$, that could either be negative, positive, or dependent on the side you approach $c$ from (left or right). In any case, the one-sided limits will be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ and *the limit* will be either of these if it is independent on the side you're approaching $c$ from.

Answer (score 1):

The limits equalling zero are right because
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{1}{g(x)}=0=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{1}{h(x)}
$$
The limits of $\pm\infty$ may or may not be correct.  It depends on the signs of $f$.

Examples:

1. $g(x)=\frac{1}{x-c}$ and $f(x)=x-c$.  Then $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{(x-c)^2}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=+\infty$.
2. $g(x)=\frac{1}{x-c}$ and $f(x)=c-x$.  Then $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{-1}{(x-c)^2}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=-\infty$.
3. $g(x)=\frac{1}{x-c}$ and $f(x)=|x-c|$.  Then for $x>c$, $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{(x-c)^2}$, while for $x<c$, $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{-1}{(x-c)^2}$.  Therefore, $\lim_{x\rightarrow c^+}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow c^-}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=-\infty$.  So the limit doesn't exist (infinite limits don't really exist, but the fraction doesn't converge to either infinite value).
4. $g(x)=\frac{1}{x-c}$ and $f(x)=(x-c)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-c}\right)$.  Then, as $x$ approaches $c$, $f(x)$ oscillates between positive and negative values.  In this case, $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{(x-c)^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-c}\right)}$, which is undefined at countably many places near $c$, but at the values where its defined, it becomes close to either $\infty$ and $-\infty$ infinitely often.